# Can we apply Bayes rule to only one variable of a conditional joint distribution?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

We know this is a valid manipulation:

$$P(X, Y | Z) = \frac{P(Z | X, Y)P(X, Y)}{P(Z)}$$

and in general, if we have a constant "conditioned set" we can apply the standard manipulations for expanding joint distributions (for example) using the product rule of probability:

$$P(X, Y | Z) = P(X|Y, Z) P(Y|Z)$$

with the same logic applying for Bayes rule. Now, say we have the following:

$$P(X, Y | Z, H)$$

can we in general write:

$$P(X, Y | Z, H) = \frac{P(X, Z|Y, H)P(Y|H)}{P(Z, H)}$$

intuitively I imagine this would only be the case if we can guarantee certain independence properties?

EDIT:

Having worked out the algebra a little bit it seems that the only way we can say this is when $P(Z|Y,H) = 1$ ?

Comment: Bayes rule gives $$P(X, Y | Z, H) = \frac{P(X, Z|Y, H)P(Y,H)}{P(Z, H)}$$ so I dont think that we can use your formula in general

Comment: ah ok I see, we would need $P(Y|H)P(H)$ or as you write the equivalent term, in terms of the joint distribution